# Even after enabling php_fileinfo I get error:unable to guess mime type

Tags: php, laravel, png

Even after enabling php_fileinfo i get error:unable to guess mime type in laravel 5. Please note I have enabled php_fileinfo.dll in php.ini and also I see that extension is enabled.

Please help.

Comment: Can you add more complete error messages? And also what kind of file that you trying to upload?

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment out the following line from your php.ini and then restart your apache

> extension = php_fileinfo.dll